# How to use DI by Unity in Winform?

Tags: c#, winforms, dependency-injection, unity-container, mvp

I have the Unity DI container working initially with my Windows Forms application. When I run my program, an unhandled exception of type '**System.StackOverflowException**' occurred in Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll. What is my mistake in this code? How can fix it?

```
public static class Program
{
    private static void Main()
    {
        var container = BuildUnityContainer();
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(container.Resolve<Form1>());
    }

    public static IUnityContainer BuildUnityContainer()
    {
        var currentContainer = new UnityContainer() ;
        currentContainer.RegisterType<IUserViewPresenter, UserViewPresenter>();
        currentContainer.RegisterType<IUserView, Form1>();
        return currentContainer;
    }
}

public partial class Form1 : Form, IUserView
{
    private readonly IUserViewPresenter _presenter;

    public Form1(IUserViewPresenter presenter)
    {
        _presenter = presenter;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return firstName.Text; }
        set { firstName.Text = value; }
    }

    public string LastName
    {
        get { return lastName.Text; }
        set { lastName.Text = value; }
    }
}

public interface IUserView
{
    string FirstName { set; get; }

    string LastName { set; get; }
}

public class UserViewPresenter : IUserViewPresenter
{
    readonly IUserView _view;

    public UserViewPresenter(IUserView view)
    {
        _view = view;
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        _view.FirstName = "Arman";
        _view.LastName = "Arian";
    }
}

public interface IUserViewPresenter
{
    void Save();
}
```

Comment: Why not Application.Run(container.Resolve<IUserView>());?

Comment: Please see the stacktrace for more informations... unity is really very difficult to see the exception you need see the stacktrace...

Answer (score 4):

You have an infinite recursion loop.

1. You call container.Resolve()
2. Unity inspects Form1 constructor and sees an instance of an IUserView needs to be constructed.
3. Unity inspects the UserViewPresenter and sees an instance of an Form1 needs to be constructed.
4. Goto 2.
5. StackOverflow

If you can get rid of your circular reference, your problem would be solved.  And my recommendation.

-or-

You could register each with a PerResolveLifetimeManager.  Then it would only construct one of each type each time you call resolve.

```
currentContainer.RegisterType<IUserViewPresenter, UserViewPresenter>(new PerResolveLifetimeManager());
currentContainer.RegisterType<IUserView, Form1>(new PerResolveLifetimeManager());
```

Comment: Can u give me sample with PerResolveLifetimeManager in my context?

Comment: Updated answer with sample.

Answer (score 0):

For the resolution of the problem:

```
private static void Main()
{
    var container = BuildUnityContainer();
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Application.Run(new Form1());
}
```

However i dont recommend you to do that...

For your case i recommend a lot this link: [Here](http://foyzulkarim.blogspot.com.br/2012/09/using-dependency-injection-unity-to.html)

If you are interested in do it on a WPF enviroment:

Take a look on [PRISM pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg406140.aspx)

[Bootstrap especifically](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg430868(v=pandp.40).aspx)

Comment: That won't work as Form1 has no parameterless constructor.